# Expectation value of Pauli Z for locally rotated Bell state

Tags: measurement, quantum-operation

Suppose we have a Bell state $\frac{\lvert 00 \rangle + \lvert 11 \rangle}{\sqrt{2}}$. The expectation value of the Bell state with respect to $Z \otimes I $ is $\langle Bell|Z_1|Bell\rangle = 0$. Now, suppose we act a unitary $U$ to the first qubit so that the new state is $(U_1 \otimes I)(\frac{\lvert 00 \rangle + \lvert 11 \rangle}{\sqrt{2}})$. Is the expectation value of this state with respect to $Z \otimes I$ still 0, i.e. $\langle Bell|(U^\dagger Z U \otimes I)|Bell\rangle = 0$ for any $U$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should still be zero since the reduced density matrix for the Bell state is $\rho_1 = \mathbb{1}/2$.

Just to check, any expectation value in the Bell state is given by
$$\left\langle A \right\rangle = \left\langle \text{Bell} \middle| A\otimes \mathbb{1} \middle| \text{Bell} \right\rangle = \text{tr} \left[\, \frac{1}{2} \left( \left| 00 \middle\rangle \hspace{-0.3mm} \middle\langle 00 \right| + \left| 11 \middle\rangle \hspace{-0.3mm} \middle\langle 11 \right| \right) \, A \otimes \mathbb{1} \, \right] \\
= \frac{1}{2} \, \text{tr} \left[ \, A \, \right] \, = \, \frac{1}{2} \text{tr} \left[ \,U^{\dagger}\, A \, U \, \right]\, ,$$
for any $U$.

Any Bell state is basically the maximally mixed state as far as any single-qubit measurement (meaning both outcomes $\pm 1$ are equally likely, so the expectation value is zero).

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way to justify this if to notice that fr any single qubit unitary $U$, acting on the Bell state $|B\rangle$,
$$
U\otimes U^\star|B\rangle=|B\rangle.
$$
So, I can rewrite
$$
U\otimes I|B\rangle=I\otimes U^T|B\rangle.
$$
Thus, when I calculate
$$
\langle B|(U^\dagger\otimes I)(Z\otimes I)(U\otimes I)|B\rangle,
$$
I can move both the $U$s onto the second qubit,
$$
=\langle B|(Z\otimes (U^\star U^T))|B\rangle
$$
where they cancel, so you can see it must give the same answer.